Create 20digit unqueid without using newid() func
I want to create a UniqueId Generator just as NEWID() as it helps in creating 32 bits unique digits.
Here I dont want to use NEWID() because  I need a fixed length of 20 digits once in a chance there is the highest probability of creating duplicate. Which will lead to application dump.
Help me with the possible ways I can create a unique id list.
SELECT LEN((REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff'), '-', ''), ':', ''), '.', ''))),

(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmssfff'), '-', ''), ':', ''), '.', ''))

this won't work as running the statement more than one time it is giving me the same output. as it  being executed in same microsecond. 'fff'.

Didn't you ask this just the other day?

didnt got the answere, its just AS newid() genreates 32 digits uniqueid's
I want to create 20 digits unique code generator . Really into a problem.Help me in finding solutions, how can i make 20 digits unique id generator

Asking the same question again will get you the same comments again plus some downvotea because deleting and re-asking the same question goes against the site policy

The last time you said you wanted to uniquify 10k numbers but only want to have 3 numbers to do it, which sounds a bit impossible. Have you resolved this issue? I asked if you really need microseconds, if you remove them, you can just use ROW_NUMBER for the rest of the numbers

You can do something like: SELECT LEFT((cast(FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmssff') AS numeric(22, 0)) * 10000) + row_number() OVER(ORDER BY @@spid), 20) FROM yourtable 

If you want/need a 20 digit unique identifier, you can use a sequence.
create sequence dbo.mySeq
    as numeric(20, 0)
    start with 1
    no cycle
    cache 100;

It's a proper object in your database and can be used in a default constraint on a column an one or multiple tables.

That said, I challenge your reasoning for not wanting to use GUIDs in general (of which NEWID() is but one way of obtaining one). First, it's exceedingly unlikely that you'll get a duplicate. But let's say you do get a duplicate. That's not necessarily an application crash. Surely whatever application-side code you have has the notion of error handling, right? Handle the the duplicate key error and perhaps try the insert again?
Also, note that a 20 digit ID space is considerably smaller than the GUID space. While academic (i.e. you're not likely to have 10^20 rows in your table), the number of bits in 10^20 = log_2 (10^20) = 20 * log_2 10 ≈ 66 bits which is about half of the 128 bits in a GUID.

Why not combine the two approaches?  Use a partially constructed Unique Identifier based on the date with 5 digits from a NEWID() field?  I would think the possibility of duplication within .003 seconds would be virtually nill.
SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'yyMMddHHmmssfff')+LEFT(NEWID(),5) AS UniqID


You may not want the entire GUID value produced by NEWID(), but you can use the random portions of that GUID value to generate an almost perfectly evenly distributed random 20-digit number.
The following will extract the leftmost 6 bytes and rightmost 6 bytes from the GUID's binary representation, convert each of those to BIGINT values (48 bits yields about 15 digits), trim each value to 10 digits, and combine them to give you a 20-digit result.
SELECT N.N20
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,100) S
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(16)) AS GuidBytes16) G
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT
        RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(G.GuidBytes16, 1, 6) AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(16)), 10)
        +RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(G.GuidBytes16, 11, 6) AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(16)), 10)
        AS N20
) N

It makes no difference if you use the same or different GUIDs for the two parts. If you don't mind two NEWID() calls per result, the following single expression  can be used.
    SELECT
        RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(16)), 1, 6) AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(16)), 10)
        +RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(16)), 11, 6) AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(16)), 10)
        AS N20

Sample results:
58456226626404201259
05151118136372540255
31009780330345614705
01252928179162992151
24716926939075256174
78661155819550015733
55052669606325101712
20182245438468337275
37973830841599165231
56918728247601686340

See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
Using the birthday problem square approximation rule of thumb, you would have about:

A 1 in 2,000,000 chance of a collision after allocating 10,000,000 values.
A 1 in 20,000 chance of a collision after allocating 100,000,000 values.
A 1 in 200 chance of a collision after allocating 1,000,000,000 values.

If that is not good enough, you can look at the create sequence answer posted by @BenThul.
